# How to access Speech Recognition via Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, vb6, speech-recognition

I'm trying to update a very old VB6 program to provide Speech Recognition.
I'm thinking the best way to do this is by accessing the Win32 API for Speech Recognition.

Looked for this on MS documentation. Looks like previously this would be done via the SAPI 5.3 per this question which has been deprecated and replaced by MS Agent, which itself is deprecated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/speech

Comment: For VB6 you'd almost certainly want to find some ActiveX control. And just because something is marked deprecated, keep in mind MS is very unlikely to actually remove it. VB6 itself has to be considered deprecated, if something works with it now I wouldn't be concerned about official support going forward.

Comment: VB6 runtime is not deprecated at all, it is completely supported in Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy  ... which reads "The Visual Basic team is committed to "It Just Works" compatibility for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on the following supported Windows operating systems:

Windows 11
Windows 10".  Though the VB6 *development tools* are no longer supported.

Comment: The question reads like there would be some links in it, but there are none. Can you edit and add them?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720589(VS.85).aspx

The above link is old (because I used it 10 years ago), but is valid.  You basically create the appropriate objects, possibly create a grammar in their format, and then create events on the `RC` object, below:

The below method "works", but it wasn't very impressive.  Also, it led us to have to create our own `MsgBox` function, since we needed to automate **everything**...  And, since you can't just tell Windows to "click" the OK button of a standard message box (unless you want to muck around even more APIs), you have to control even more aspects of your software.

It did work, but I'm not sure anyone ever used it.

```
Public WithEvents RC As SpSharedRecoContext
Public myGrammar, b As ISpeechRecoGrammar

Private Sub Form_Load()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Set RC = New SpSharedRecoContext

    Set myGrammar = RC.CreateGrammar
    myGrammar.CmdLoadFromFile "sol.xml", SLODynamic
    myGrammar.CmdSetRuleIdState 0, SGDSActive

EH:
    If Err.Number Then ShowErrMsg
End Sub

Private Sub RC_FalseRecognition(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant, ByVal Result As SpeechLib.ISpeechRecoResult)
    'Label1.Caption = "(no recognition)"
End Sub

Private Sub RC_Recognition(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant, ByVal RecognitionType As SpeechLib.SpeechRecognitionType, ByVal Result As SpeechLib.ISpeechRecoResult)
    'Label1.Caption = Result.PhraseInfo.GetText
End Sub

Private Sub RC_StartStream(ByVal StreamNumber As Long, ByVal StreamPosition As Variant)
    'Label2.Caption = Val(StreamNumber)
End Sub
```